# TypeError: cannot read property 'onMarksSelection' of undefined. When trying to attach a event listener to a tableau viz using React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tableau-api

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCcWy.png)

`TypeError: cannot read property 'onMarksSelection' of undefined.`

Hello,

I am trying to attach a listener to my Tableau Viz to register selected Data points from that Viz.

The Dashboard renders and the listeners to work in plain HTML and simple JS Using the Tableau API [Documentation](https://help.tableau.com/current/api/js_api/en-us/JavaScriptAPI/js_api.htm).

However, when I went to implement the same thing in React JS I have gotten some errors. Specifically the one in the screenshot above. The Dashboard will render correctly but when I try and attach the listener I get the error.

I have written this function per the API documentation but I'm not sure what is not working on it.

The code for the listener function is attached below.

```
onMarksSelection(marksEvent) {
  return marksEvent.getMarksAsync().then(function (marks) {

    var dataPoints = [];
    for (var markIndex = 0; markIndex < marks.length; markIndex++) {
      var pairs = marks[markIndex].getPairs();
      dataPoints.push(pairs);
    }
    return this.setState({points: dataPoints});
  });
}

listenToMarksSelection() {
  Viz.addEventListener(window.tableau.TableauEventName.MARKS_SELECTION, this.onMarksSelection);   
  // Error is coming from this line ^^^^
```

}

Knowing that it did work in plain HTML I'm thinking the issue is something with my react knowledge.

EDIT:: Added rest of code and changed the .then function for clarity

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import tableau from "tableau-api";
import Table from '../Table';


const OuterBox = styled.div `
  min-height: 600px;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
`
var Viz;

class MapContainer extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    viz: null,
    containerDiv: null,
    url: null,
    options: null,
    points: []
  };
}

reportSelectedMarks(marks) {

   var dataPoints = [];
   for (var markIndex = 0; markIndex < marks.length; markIndex++) {
     var pairs = marks[markIndex].getPairs();
     dataPoints.push(pairs);
   }
   return this.setState({points: dataPoints});


 }

onMarksSelection(marksEvent) {
  return marksEvent.getMarksAsync().then(this.reportSelectedMarks());
}

listenToMarksSelection() {

  Viz.addEventListener(window.tableau.TableauEventName.MARKS_SELECTION, this.onMarksSelection);
}


loadViz(){
    this.state.containerDiv = document.getElementById("tableauViz");
    this.state.url = "URL TAKEN OUT for security but goes here";
    this.state.options = {
            width:  "100%",
            height: "600px",
            hideTabs: true,
            onFirstInteractive: function () {
                console.log("Run this code when the viz has finished loading.");
            }
        };
    Viz  = new window.tableau.Viz(this.state.containerDiv, this.state.url, this.state.options);
    // Create a viz object and embed it in the container div.
}



removeMarksSelectionEventListener() {
  Viz.removeEventListener(window.tableau.TableauEventName.MARKS_SELECTION, this.onMarksSelection());
}

componentDidMount(){
    this.loadViz();
}

render() {
    return (
      <OuterBox id="outerBox">
        <div id="tableauViz">
        </div>
        <div id="Buttons">
          <button onClick={this.listenToMarksSelection}>Start listening</button>
          <button onClick={this.removeMarksSelectionEventListener}>Run this code</button>
        </div>
      </OuterBox>
    );
}
```

}

export default MapContainer;

Comment: Can you please share the full snippet of this component. It seems the `execution context` i.e. **this** isn't correct. Secondly, I can see couple of issues with the onMarksSelection function. You should try either returning the values of `dataPoints` or you should try removing second `return` from that function.

Comment: @Jawadulhassan I have attached the rest of the component. Do you mean that I need to bind the .this ?     Also I know about the errors that I have with the not using setState but by using setState I was getting different errors so that is why it is used in some places and not others

Comment: I have tried making changes to your code according to your mentioned error. Let me know if that works or not.

Comment: Hello, I tried making the changes you suggested but the same error was there.  I tried looking into the execution context like you suggested and it got rid of the original error but then I was getting this error on getMarksAsync   Screenshot of error https://ibb.co/2hhq167

Comment: Can you please `console.log` the marksEvent and comment the snippet in here?

Comment: I did that and it said it was `undefined`.     https://ibb.co/9HSQs6h This is how I accomplished the same code in plain JS.  and now knowing that marksEvent is undefined it must be the way that variable is being passed from `listenToMarksSelection`  to `onMarksSelection` Which I'm guessing just means im doing passing it the wrong way in react.   I tried using an arrow function like you suggested before,  shown here https://ibb.co/RNgChnB but still got that marksEvent was undefined.

Comment: @Jawadulhassan I know it been a couple of days but did what I provide help?

Comment: can you please provide me with the snippet of **marksEvent** which you consoled in here [https://ibb.co/RNgChnB]?

Answer (score 0):

The updated code which should fix the above mentioned error:

```
import React from "react";
import tableau from "tableau-api";
import styled from "styled-components";

import Table from "../Table";

const OuterBox = styled.div`
  min-height: 600px;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
`;

var Viz;

class MapContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      viz: null,
      containerDiv: null,
      url: null,
      options: null,
      points: []
    };
  }

  reportSelectedMarks(marks) {
    var dataPoints = [];
    for (var markIndex = 0; markIndex < marks.length; markIndex++) {
      var pairs = marks[markIndex].getPairs();
      dataPoints.push(pairs);
    }
    this.setState({ points: dataPoints });
  }

  onMarksSelection(marksEvent) {
    return marksEvent
      .getMarksAsync()
      .then(marks => this.reportSelectedMarks(marks));
  }

  listenToMarksSelection() {
    Viz.addEventListener(
      window.tableau.TableauEventName.MARKS_SELECTION,
      this.onMarksSelection()
    );
  }

  loadViz() {
    this.state.containerDiv = document.getElementById("tableauViz");
    this.state.url = "URL TAKEN OUT for security but goes here";
    this.state.options = {
      width: "100%",
      height: "600px",
      hideTabs: true,
      onFirstInteractive: function() {
        console.log("Run this code when the viz has finished loading.");
      }
    };
    Viz = new window.tableau.Viz(
      this.state.containerDiv,
      this.state.url,
      this.state.options
    );
    // Create a viz object and embed it in the container div.
  }

  removeMarksSelectionEventListener() {
    Viz.removeEventListener(
      window.tableau.TableauEventName.MARKS_SELECTION,
      this.onMarksSelection()
    );
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.loadViz();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <OuterBox id="outerBox">
        <div id="tableauViz"></div>
        <div id="Buttons">
          <button onClick={this.listenToMarksSelection}>Start listening</button>
          <button onClick={this.removeMarksSelectionEventListener}>
            Run this code
          </button>
        </div>
      </OuterBox>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error  `TypeError: Cannot read property 'onMarksSelection' of undefined`.  It looks like it is coming from the listenToMarksSelection function when it tries to call onMarksSelection